# LiClipse pydev editor color setting resets itself

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, pydev, liclipse

I have LiClipse with below version. I can change for example, annotation color in preference editor, but after I exit LiClipse and relaunch it, the color resets back to default. Is there a config file that I can edit directly to force the color change?

> Version: 4.0.0.201706061723
>   com.brainwy.liclipse.rcp.product

Answer (score 1):

In LiClipse you're expected to edit only the theme. All colors -- including annotations -- are then updated to match the theme (they're applied when you change the theme and when it's restarted).

So, to fix your issue, you should edit the theme itself.

Go to the `preferences > general > appearance > color theme` and to change the theme click on `edit theme`.

Not sure which of the annotation related colors you want to edit without a better description, but the most common is for occurrences, which is given by `occurrenceIndication`.

---

As a note, another solution could be choosing `Don't reapply settings on restart`, so it wouldn't apply the theme on restart, but things may become unsynchronized then and changing the theme would override your manual changes too.

Comment: i ended up fixing the problem by deleting the current workspace and creating a new one. I believe there was some file corruption in the previous workspace.